# How to get an exact 6 month date range?

Tags: c#, datetime

I need a help to get the six-month range from the current date. For example, if the current date is `02-Feb-2016` then I would want start date `01-Sep-2015` and an end date `29-Feb-2016`.

I have tried the code:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2016,02,06);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
DateTime startDate = endDate.AddMonths(-6);
```

And Output is:

```
Startdate: 29-Aug-2015 endDate: 29-Feb-2016
```

But I want the following output:

```
 Startdate: 01-Sep-2015 endDate: 29-Feb-2016
```

Update:

I have updated the question with an example which I had tried and output.

juharr's comment is the work for me.

Comment: Why on earth would `DateTime.AddMonths()` _subtract_ days unless you gave it a negative value? Show us your code and the output you get, please.

Comment: Neither of those dates in the range you're expecting seems to have anything to do with the current date like you say. Can you explain what you really want? Do you mean current month instead of date?

Comment: The 6-month rule isn't clear. Do you mean the 6 months ending at the end of the current month, or do you have a specific 6-month period defined (always Sept-Feb-Sept)?

Comment: @VisualVincent you answered your own question. It's not as rare as you might think to do that

Comment: @Rhumborl : And that's why I want to see his code.

Comment: Op would you care sharing your code with a clean example, please look at [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions) for any further posts in future

Comment: Change the `startDate` to `new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1).AddMonths(-5);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Moving juharr's comment as an answer, as it is correct*

Simply change:

```
DateTime startDate = endDate.AddMonths(-6);
```

to

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1).AddMonths(-5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based in the example in your question this should work for you:

```
DateTime end = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Year, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).Month, 1).AddDays(-1);
DateTime start = end.AddMonths(-6);
```

Comment: or `var end = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddMonth(1).AddDay(-1);`  Also the `start` is going to to be the last day of the month instead of the first, so instead `var start = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DataTime.Now.Month, 1).AddMonths(-5)`.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, 180 days is not exactly six months.  It looks like you need -3 months and +3 months.  This will give you a six month breakout.

For months:

```
var dat = new DateTime(2016, 01, 01);
var startdat = dat.AddMonths(-3);
var enddat = dat.AddMonths(3);
```

however, if you really did mean 180 days....

For days:

```
var dat = new DateTime(2016, 01, 01);
var startdat = dat.AddDays(-90);
var enddat = dat.AddDays(90);
```

Now you have the two dates you need.

UPDATE 1:
if you just need -6 months, your function did work, but as I mentioned before, -180 days is not the same thing as -6 months.

You can still use the `AddDays(-180)` if you want 180 days, or `AddMonths(-6)` for 6 months back.

Comment: "It looks like you need -3 months and +3 months" - How do you figure? Op gave the date `02-Feb-2016` and expected to get back `01-Sep-2015` till `29-Feb-2016`.

Comment: His question said, "I need a six month range".  That's what I was responding to. I didn't see the other part.